# Enabling and accessing Social Persona and Social Post fields

Tags: social-contacts, socialpost

Can anyone clarify the following about Social Persona and Social Post objects?

1. In a developer instance, do I need to open a case to enable visibility of Social Persona and Social Post objects in the Setup UI?  I have Social Accounts/Contacts enabled but the Persona and Post do not appear in the Setup menu.
2. Are SocialPersona and SocialPost accessible to the API?  When I'm in the Developer Workbench or Dev Console, those objects are not available for SOQL queries.  However I can create triggers on Persona and Post via the Setup UI in the sandbox, and the Social Customer Service Implementation Guide refers to an Apex class that you can customize and which references SocialPersona and SocialPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version of Radian6, the Social Persona and Social Post menu options appear in Setup, and the objects are accessible to SOQL queries.